# get text between html tags correctly

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I want to grab the text between html tags using Dreamweaver's search and replace tool.

The link format is a standard a tag e.g.

```
<a href="http://alink.com">Text</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="http://alink.com">Text</a> and <a href="http://alink2.com">Text 2</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="http://alink.com" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

I am using the following expression:

```
<a href="(.*)">(.*)</a>
```

This works fine for example 1, but it picks up everything between the first opening tag `<a href` and the last closing tag `</a>` in the case of example 2.

What can I do to just targeting each individual link?

Also, what can I do in the case of example 3 where links also have a `target="_blank"` property?

Comment: which language are you using

Comment: It's 2012. [Use an XML parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: [I need to warn you to not to use regex to parse HTML text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I'm actually using Dreamweaver's search and replace tool.

Comment: Then don't use a search and replace tool. Use a language that has an XML parsing library.

Comment: go and read the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want the "Text" in the body of the  tag

```
<a[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>
```

would work

if you also want the href

```
<a[^>]*href="([^>"]*)"[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>
```

Comment: [The pony he comes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)